# MongoDB c# driver FilterDefinition not working

Tags: c#, mongodb

im trying to implement a generic repository with Mongo Db and c#, to query a collection of music albuns, it is the first time im working with mongodb so probably I'm missing some concepts.

My Albun collection has documents with a "Title" and im trying to query for an album with an specific title.I have this method in my Repository to query for a single object:

```
public async Task<GetOneResult<TEntity>> GetOne<TEntity>(FilterDefinition<TEntity> filter) where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        var res = new GetOneResult<TEntity>();
        try
        {
            var collection = GetCollection<TEntity>();
            var entity = await collection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                res.Entity = entity;
            }
            res.Success = true;
            return res;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return res;
        }
    }
```

And im tryng to retrieve the album by creating an FIlterDefinition like this:

```
_context = new LibaryRepository();
        FilterDefinition<Book> filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Eq("Title", "Besos de Perro");
        GetOneResult<Book> book = await _context.GetOne<Book>(filter);
```

I know there is an Album with this Title in my MongoDb the connection is correctly set up and connects but the query always return null as it didnt find it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call find synchronously? (by removing async and await)

Comment: I called it synchronously and still returns null value